# Где правильно ставить ударение?

Tags: орфоэпия

*"Не пишешь мне и не звонишь".* Где ударение в слове звонишь?

Answer (score 3):

Правильно ударение ставить на "и": [звонИшь](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x).